# MKMapView not showing current location, or rather, any location (in simulator)

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I have a MKMapView with it's delegate set to my controller (m) class.

Code below:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Create location manager object
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // Make this instance of WhereamiAppDelegate the delegate
    // it will send its messages to our WhereamiApplDelegate
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    // We want all results from the location manager
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

However, all I am seeing is a map of the world without a blue annotation dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator does not "really" support that. If you bypass enough checks, it will display Apple's HQ. Any GPS testing you need a real device.

EDIT: I believe that you can drop a pin and it will display that but as far as callbacks from CLLocationManager (via CLLocationManagerDelegate), it ain't happin in the simulator; at least the most recent ones.  I can't speak for anything prior to 3.0...

Answer (score 1):

```
self.mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    self.mapview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

This is all you need if you have a pointer to your map called mapView, but as Merky said, you need a real device. What you can do though is, when the simulator is running, go to "Debug ->location -> own location" and input the coords of your desired coordinate.